# Previous years OS Codepoint files

Tags: data, united-kingdom, ordnance-survey

I need to do some analysis on UK postcodes that move location and by how much. As such I need previous versions of OS Codepoint files. I only need 1 file per year, ideally going back 5 years.

Anyone out there know where I can get my hands on this data? Ordnance Survey only appear to keep the latest update on their site.

I only have the the last two updates so am lacking the last 4 yrs.

Comment: This sounds like a question more suited to researching/asking at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Searched a good couple of hours before asking on here. Will try the Open Data Stack.